# Forwarding message to syslog server

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

There are various network devices that would like to send syslog messages to [Syslog-NG](https://www.syslog-ng.com/products/open-source-log-management/) server, listening at port 514.

Below is the architecture for client-server communication.

### [image]

Is the device suppose to install Syslog-NG client to forward the message to Syslog-NG server?

What does it take for a device(client) to send message to Syslog-NG server?

Answer (score 1):

syslog-ng can receive and parse messages from a lot of different sources and formats. You can install syslog-ng on the clients, but it is not mandatory. If the device has a logging application installed that can send standard syslog messages (RFC3164 or RFC5424), that's enough. Most networking devices and Linux/UNIX servers have such applications installed by default.